# Is it possible to create a binding property from a computed property in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

In my model data class I have a task array.

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks: [Task] = Task.sampleData
}
```

In my HomeView I display these tasks however the user has the ability to use a picker to sort them by the date they were created or by the date they are due. In the HomeView I have an enum that contains the options that the user can sort them by and a state instance to hold the picked value. By default it is set to sort by due date.

```
@EnvironmentObject private var model: Model
@State private var sortOption: SortOption = .dueDate

enum SortOption {
    case dueDate, creationDate
}
```

I decided to then create a computed value that contains the sorted array so I don't change the original tasks array as it is used to display tasks in other parts of the app.

```
var sortedTasks: [Task] {
    model.tasks.sorted(by: {
        if sortOption == .dueDate {
            return $0.dueDate < $1.dueDate
        } else {
            return $0.creationDate < $1.creationDate
        }
    })
}
```

And soon after I ran into the problem. My Task Row requires a binding task and I am unable to retrieve the required binding from the computed property which was the sortedTasks array.

```
// ERROR: Cannot find '$sortedTasks' in scope
ForEach($sortedTasks) { $task in
    TaskRow(task: $task)
}
```

My understanding is that if I want to keep the sortedTasks array then I will have to remove the binding property from the TaskRow but if I want to keep the binding property what should the approach be to display a sorted array without manipulating the tasks array in the data model class? Could the computed property return a sorted array of binding task objects?

Comment: A computed can not be a binding var by definition : it has no memory location. It can be seen as the result of a function. if you want binding because you want to update task in your model you should use a method that can update a task in the model from a copy of the task : find the task index in the array then modify the indexth element of the array.

Comment: Another possibility is that the sorting happens in the model using a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t do that but you can use a `Combine` approach here:

Move your `sortedTasks`, `sortOption` var to your class named `Model` and create a combined publisher from your two vars that should trigger the `sortedTasks` var to update. Sort the received collection and assign it to your `sortedTasks`.

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks: [TaskModel] = TaskModel.sampleData
    
    @Published var sortedTasks: [TaskModel] = TaskModel.sampleData
    @Published var sortOption: SortOption = .dueDate

    init(){
        Publishers.CombineLatest($sortOption, $tasks)
            .map{ sortOption, tasks in 
               // apply sorting here
            }.assign(to: &$sortedTasks) // assign to your sorted var
    }
    
}
```

Use it like:

```
var body: some View{
        HStack{
            ForEach($model.sortedTasks) { $task in
//                TaskRow(task: $task)
            }
        }
}
```

I´ve renamed the `Task` model to `TaskModel` as i think it is a very bad idea to have a struct named after a system provided class.

Comment: This was exactly what I was after! thank you! I will have to start using the Combine framework more often in development now.

Comment: The TaskRow contains a checkbox and when I tap it, the completed boolean toggles for the task object in the sortedTasks but not the tasks array causing inconsistency. Can this be solved using combine?

Comment: @Jack this can be resolved. But i consider this a complete new question. As a hint: Create a `Binding` for that toggle that triggers a function in your `Model` class (that in reality is a viemodel :)) that updates the original collection and therefor the sorted one.

Comment: @Jack or the easier approach: make the unsorted collection private and use only the sorted.

Comment: The obvious problem with moving the sort to the model is now you cant have 2 views with different sort options.

Comment: @malhal id don´t see why you are criticizing an answer for not fulfilling a theoretical, madeup requirement?

Answer (score 3):

Sorting depends on `sortOption` which is view state so it shouldn't be done in the model because then you can't have different views using different sort options. One solution is to sort the bindings, not the tasks, e.g.

```
var sortedTasks: [Binding<Task>] {
    $model.tasks.sorted { $x, $y in // $model.tasks.animation().sorted if you would like animations like List row moves.
        if sortOption == .dueDate {
            return x.dueDate < y.dueDate
        } else {
            return x.creationDate < y.creationDate
        }
    }
}

ForEach(sortedTasks) { $task in
    TaskRow(task: $task)
}
```

You might be wondering how `ForEach` can find the `id`, well that's because `Binding` has `@dynamicMemberLookup` which means it forwards property lookups to its value.

Comment: This is a great answer. If I could accept multiple answers as the solution this would be one! Thank you very much for the descriptive solution.