# Using bindings when flattening a hierarchical list in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following code given as the answer from [this previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75829591/displaying-a-hierarchical-folder-structure-as-a-flat-list):

```
struct Folder: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var items: [Int]
    let children: [Folder]
    
    init(items: [Int], children: [Folder]) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.items = items
        self.children = children
    }
    
    var flatList: [Int] {
        var items = items
        items.append(contentsOf: children.flatMap { $0.flatList })
        return items
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var parentFolder: Folder = Folder(items: [0, 1, 2, 3], children: [
        Folder(items: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], children: [
            Folder(items: [9, 10, 11, 12], children: [])
        ])
    ])
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(parentFolder.flatList, id: \.self) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do more though. Instead of accessing the `flatList` as a copy of the data in `items` and the `items` in each child in `children`, I'd like to access the items as *bindings*. In other words, I want to be able to view the items in the whole hierarchical structure as a list, but I'd like to be able to modify each item in the list as well.

I've tried modifying `flatList` so that it returns `[Binding<Food>]` instead, but I can't quite get it to work. Ideally I'd replace the first line of `flatList` with something like

```
var items = items.map { Binding(get: { $0 }, set: { ...? }) }
```

But I'm not sure what to replace `...?` by.

Comment: First you need to fix the code so your `Item` is `Identifiable` and not an `Int`. `id: \.self` will cause a crash.

Comment: here is a way to transform an array of bindings https://stackoverflow.com/a/71841571/259521

Comment: You have a way to create a flat list out of your hierarchy but as I see it you can’t reverse that, i.e recreate the hierarchy from the list, so when you want to use bindings to delete or modify items it’s only the list you are interested in. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach of using `ObservableObject` classes to model your `Item` and `Folder`.
With this approach, you can edit the desired `Item` from your flat list,
and have this reflected in the UI, as shown in the example code. Although nesting observable classes is not ideal, there seems to be exceptions, such as here.

```
class Item: Identifiable, ObservableObject {  // <-- here
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Folder: Identifiable, ObservableObject {  // <-- here
    let id = UUID()
    var items: [Item]
    let children: [Folder]
    
    init(items: [Item], children: [Folder]) {
        self.items = items
        self.children = children
    }
    
    var flatList: [Item] {
        var items = items
        items.append(contentsOf: children.flatMap { $0.flatList } )
        return items
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
    // -- here
    @StateObject var parentFolder = Folder(items: [Item(name: "item-1"), Item(name: "item-2"),Item(name: "item-3")], children: [
        Folder(items: [Item(name: "item-4"), Item(name: "item-5"),Item(name: "item-6")], children: [
            Folder(items: [Item(name: "item-7"), Item(name: "item-8")], children: [])
        ])
    ])

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(parentFolder.flatList) { item in
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.name)
                    TextField("", text: Binding<String>(
                        get: { item.name },
                        set: {
                             parentFolder.objectWillChange.send() // <-- the important bit
                             item.name = $0
                        })
                    ).border(.blue)
                     .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }
                Divider()
            }
        }
    }

}
```